# Objective-C: Decode Signed Request

Tags: objective-c, base64

How do I decode a signed request in Objective-C?

Basically, how do I translate this Ruby code to Objective-C or C?

```
# Facebook sends a signed_requests to authenticate certain requests.
# http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/
def decode_signed_request(signed_request)
  encoded_signature, encoded_data = signed_request.split('.')
  signature = base64_url_decode(encoded_signature)
  expected_signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', @secret, encoded_data)
  if signature == expected_signature
    JSON.parse base64_url_decode(encoded_data)
  end
rescue Exception => e
  puts $!, $@
end

def base64_url_decode(string)
  "#{string}==".tr("-_", "+/").unpack("m")[0]
end
```

[SSToolKit Base64 decode NSString](https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/NSString+SSToolkitAdditions.m#L215-229) looks helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to verify the signature on the data or just "decode" it? If it's the latter, you can just ignore the signature:

```
NSString *signedData = ...;
NSString *base64EncodedData = [[signedData componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithBase64String:base64EncodedData];
id jsonObject = ...;
```

I leave using the Facebook SDK and choosing a suitable JSON framework (I recommend [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)) up to you.

Your comment indicates that you want to verify the HMAC included with the message. In that case:

```
unsigned int length = 0;
unsigned char *expectedHmac = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), [key bytes], [key length], [base64EncodedData UTF8String], [base64EncodedData length], NULL, &length);
NSData *expectedHmacData = [NSData dataWithBytes:expectedHmac length:length];
// compare expected hmac
```

Comment: I also want to verify the signature on the data. This is a good start though. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that. Hopefully it's more helpful now :)